# Return Full Name from Another Table in Login Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I am using asp.net core identity, but have deliberately separated the user specific information into another table which is linked via the application user class.

How would I access this information from the login partial view?

Other answers only define so far as to pull the information from the application user class. ie:

```
var personID = UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.PersonID;
```

Where as I need something like:

```
var fullName = UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Person.FullName;
```

I'm guessing the code behind doesn't load the child table, as I get the the following error on the Person object:

```
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

The rest of my code is below for reference.

Application User:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }    
    }
```

Person Class

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
    }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

Login Partial:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Models;
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
        @{
                var personResult = UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
                var fullName = personResult.Person.FullName;                
            }  
          
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post" >
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @viveknuna  `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`  On the Person object.  I'm guessing this is because the person table is not loaded in the UserManager class and I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: check the return value of `GetUserAsync`

Comment: @viveknuna It correctly returns the user object.  And I can get the PersonID, but it will not drill down further to the Person object.

Comment: does it have Person as null?

Comment: @viveknuna Yes Person is null.

Comment: Then you need to check why is this `null`

Comment: @viveknuna  That's the entire premise of my question, I suspects its null because the UserManager class does not  load the child tables by default.  So do I need to extend it somehow?  I simply don't know how to load the person table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` is based on EF Core, it won't load related data by defalut,you could try with lazyloading as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lazy-loading)

I tried as below in my case:

installed the package:

[image]

Models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    
    //you have to set the property virtual here
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
    }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    //you have to set the property virtual here
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

}
```

modified the codes which regist the dbcontext:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityLazyloadingContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
});
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understand eager and explicit loading and how to use it in normal code behind.  However I am trying to display the Username from the person table in the standard asp.net core _LoginPartial view which is a partial view with no code behind.  See the code I have added.

Comment: Oh，my fault，you could try with lazyloading to get the navigation properties,I've updated my answer,please check it

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Ruikai Feng marked as answer as it set me on the right track.  However I ended up using lazy loading without the proxies framework as follows:

[LazyLoading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        private Person _Person;

        public ApplicationUser()
        {
        }

        private ApplicationUser(Action<object, string> lazyLoader)
        {
            LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
        }

        private Action<object, string> LazyLoader { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        public Person Person
        {
            get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _Person);
            set => _Person = value;
        }
    }
```

Extension:

```
  public static class PocoLoadingExtensions
    {
        // Load function for Lazy Loading, used in Application User.

        public static TRelated Load<TRelated>(
            this Action<object, string> loader,
            object entity,
            ref TRelated navigationField,
            [CallerMemberName] string navigationName = null)
            where TRelated : class
        {
            loader?.Invoke(entity, navigationName);

            return navigationField;
        }
    }
```